# Re-integrating media library files

Tags: media-library

I'm working on upgrading a client from 6.2 Update 1 (don't faint!) to 8.2 Update 1 (thank you migration express tool). In their current environment, they have been running their media library external to the database, so when they add a media library item the physical file is written to the App_Data/MediaFiles directory.

As part of this effort, we want to re-integrate the physical files back into the database (the "default" as it were) so that the publishing/management of the media is more in line with the standard practice. I'm looking for what the best method or tool would be to perform this action.

The customer currently has one one CM and one CD environment, but we're trying to future-plan here for possibly more CD environments, and it seems using Sitecore for media management as it works "out of the box" is the best way to do this. One catch could be the files themselves are at least 100 GB when unzipped, which could certainly take some time to process.

If someone wants to suggest a file management approach instead, I'd need to know what the suggestion would be for pushing the files to CD on publish, both the file management application or process as well as a suggestion on a pipeline that might accomplish this (instead of just pushing the image on load, I figure it needs to wait for someone to publish to the web database to go to CD).

Comment: 100GB, while technically possibly, most definitely calls for a proper DAM solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to do this in the past and I had great success with the [Media Conversion Tool](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Media_Conversion_Tool.aspx), available on the [Sitecore Marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net). That was a good number of media items, but was still only around 2.5 GB as the items themselves were mostly lower-res images.

This tool brings up a media library browser and allows you to move media items from the filesystem into blob (database) storage, and vice-versa.

The tool hasn't been updated in a while so I'm not sure if it's compatible with Sitecore 8.2, and the earliest version it shows compatability for is 6.4, but the source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ivansharamok/Sitecore-Media-ConversionTool) so you might be able to fix issues if there are any.

Despite this, I think you might be right to look into an alternative option, as 100 GB of media items alone is going to make your databases large. I'll leave this as answer for an approach to move media items from the file-system into the database, but your problem might need a different approach.